# Obtener datos de un json y convertirlos en un checkbox

Tags: jquery

Tengo el archivo json en otro sitio. Quiero obtener los valores referentes al género(Estrategia, Deportes, Simulador...) de cada juego y mostrarlos en forma de checkbox, pero es que no me aclaro.

Tengo por una parte el siguiente código **HTML** donde irá anidado los valores en forma de checkbox (He puesto 2 de ejemplo):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>
            Prueba 2
        </title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="form-check">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Arcade">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="arcade">
                            Arcade
                       </label>
                      </input>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Aventuras">
                     <label class="form-check-label" for="aventuras">
                           Aventuras
                     </label>
                   </input>
             </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Y ahora en **JQuery** obtengo los valores del json que se encuentra en otro documento, pero después ya no se como continuar debido a que ya he probado varios métodos, pero todos me daban error y era un lio, por lo que he preferido quitarlo y empezar de nuevo.

```
// Objeto con el array de juegos cargado.
var listadoJuegos;

/**
 * Función que se ejecuta cuando el DOM se ha cargado completamente
 */
$( ( ) => {
    $.getJSON( 'resources/juegos.json', function ( data ) {
        listadoJuegos = data;
        $( document )
        .trigger( 'juegosCargados' );
    } );
} );

$( document )
.on( 'juegosCargados', function ( ) {
     //Aquí va el código para capturar y mostrar los elementos.
     console.log(listadoJuegos);
} );
```

Archivo **JSON**:

```
[
   {
      "titulo": "Adventure Time: Explore the Dungeon Because I DON’T KNOW!"
      , "genero": "Deportes"
      , "año": 2015
      , "precio": 10
 }
   , {
      "titulo": "Alien Spidy"
      , "genero": "Estrategia"
      , "año": 2016
      , "precio": 30
 }
   , {
      "titulo": "All Zombies Must Die!"
      , "genero": "Simulador"
      , "año": 2012
      , "precio": 15
 }
   , {
      "titulo": "Alone in the Dark: Inferno"
      , "genero": "Simulador"
      , "año": 2012
      , "precio": 15
 }
]
```

Cualquier ayuda, de verdad que seria muy agradecida

Comment: Entonces quieres que debajo del checkbox arcade, aventuras. Este otros checkboxs como deportes, estrategia, etc?

Comment: Si, aunque si a la hora de aplicar los checkbox quieres quitarlos y aplicar los otros, me es indiferente. Como más sencillo y claro lo veas tú. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrias hacer es lo siguiente:

```js
var listadoJuegos;

$.getJSON('https://api.npoint.io/d582b001175932856cd5', function(data) {
  listadoJuegos = data;
  $(document).trigger('juegosCargados');
});

$(document).on('juegosCargados', function() {
  for (const lista of listadoJuegos) {
    $('<div>', {
        'class': 'form-control'
      })
      .append($('<input>', {
        'class': 'form-check-input',
        'type': 'checkbox',
        'value': lista['genero']
      }))
      .append($('<label>', {
        'class': 'form-check-label',
        'for': lista['genero'],
        'text': ' ' + lista['genero']
      })).appendTo('#checkboxs');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="checkboxs">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Arcade">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="arcade">
      Arcade
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Aventuras">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="aventuras">
      Aventuras
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como ves, estoy utilizando el `for-of` para recorrer el JSON y agregar los datos dinamicos a un div general con `append`.

A parte de la solucion tengo unas observaciones en tu codigo:

1. No existe un input de cierre `</input>`, por lo cual al crearse seria `<input><label</label>`, de forma seguida
2. La forma en que obtienes la informacion del `getJSON`, no es recomendable, ya que haces `listadoJuegos = data;`, para estos casos es mejor usar [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas)

**Referencia**

- https://api.jquery.com/append/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of

Comment: Habría alguna forma de hacerlo sin que se repitan los elementos? Gracias por el código proporcionado anteriormente @Juan Rivera

Comment: @ShadowZ a que te refieres "sin que se repitan los elementos"? Que no se cree el `div, input, label` en cada iteracion?

Comment: No, que si por ejemplo hay un género de Simulación, si hay alguna forma de que no vuelva a salir, así que haya solo uno de cada y evitar los géneros repetidos.

Comment: Lo que podrias hacer es guardar todos los generos en una variable, despues con eso filtrar y eliminar duplicados, para que finalmente se haga la iteracion

Comment: Ya he conseguido una forma de hacerlo, ya esta solucionado, no hace falta ya. Muchas gracias por todo lo anterior @Juan Rivera